# What is the right way of sending a var on AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a javascript function that calls a Webmethod. I tried sending a regular string to the webmethod and it works. On var empid= $('#' + txtId).val() Im getting the right value of the text box. What is the right way of sending empid over ajax ? I have tried a few thing and they dont work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

.js

```
function toggle(txtId, lblname, txtcode) {

var empid = $('#' + txtId ).val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SearchEmpId.asmx/GetEmployeeName",
    data: '{ id: empid }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#' + lblname).html(data.d);

    }
});    
}
```

.asmx.vb (webmethod)

```
Public Function GetEmployeeName(ByVal id As String) As String

Return "It works"

End Function
```

This is a screen shoot when removing contentType

[image]

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal what do you mean by typo? that is how I read the data sent back from the webservice. And it works.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
data: '{ id: empid }',
```

use

```
data: { id: empid },
```

Its sending [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: After i Edited with your answer its giving me an error.  I went on the Developer Tool under Response Body its showing the message: {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: id.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n.... Any Ideas why is this happening ?

Comment: @omachu23 Try by removing the `contentType` property

Comment: I did it but its not triggering the webmethod. I updated my question with a screen shot of what I am getting on the response body now that i erase the contenType.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataType:"json" for json data

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
     data: ({name: 145}),
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
});
```

Read Docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also in PHP

```
<?php
  $userAnswer = $_POST['name']; 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM <tablname> where color='".$userAnswer."'" ;
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  // for first row only and suppose table having data
  echo json_encode($row);  // pass array in json_encode  
?>
```

Comment: There is no need for the ( and ) around the object.

Comment: I am able to send a regular string. My question is how do I set data to send my empid var ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
var empid=$('#txtEmpId').val();
```

Pass empid in data as

```
data: { id: empid },
```

Check out the fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/gN6CT/103/